# flex-shrink does not update item width

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

**Update:** I think there is no easy solution to this if I have to use flexbox. I'll just use "flex-shrink: 0" and use media queries to adjust the design. Anyway, thanks for your help.

I have got a horizontal list (display: flex) with multiple elements. When I reduce the window size the list elements start to shrink. Unfortunately, the width of the elements nearly stays the same. The li-elements take up too much space. I want the li-element's size to fit the content. If I add "flex-shrink: 0" to the li-element the width is right, but I need this word-wrap.

How to fix this?

[With flex-shrink: 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAU8Y.png)

[With flex-shrink: 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl1V9.png)

```
#categories ul {
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}

#categories li {
    padding: 0 0 7px 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```
<nav id="categories">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">
```

Thanks & regards,
Mark

Comment: When asking a CSS/HTML question you need to include the CSS/HTML.

Comment: @EternalHour Sorry, I did not think it was necessary, because there is not much code.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the `flex-shrink` property sets the `flex-shrink` of a flex container item. So the items will shrink to fit the container if they are larger than the container's size. In your case, I think that setting `flex-shrink` to `2` would make the word-wrap as you requested. Check this code snippet. I hope it helps!

```js
function myFunction(val) {
  document.getElementById("example-element").style.flexShrink = val;
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}

.buttons-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 70%;
}

.example-container {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: .2em solid;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
}

.example-container>div {
  margin: 10px;
}

.first-solution>div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

small {}

.second-solution {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.second-solution>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.third-solution {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.third-solution>div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid blue;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="buttons-section">
  <div>
    <pre><code>flex-shrink: 0;</code></pre>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(0)" aria-hidden="true">Apply
        </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <pre><code>flex-shrink: 1;</code></pre>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(1)" aria-hidden="true">Apply
        </button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <pre><code>flex-shrink: 2;</code></pre>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(2)" aria-hidden="true">Apply
        </button>
  </div>
</section>
<br>
<div>
  <section>
    <div class="example-container first-solution">
      <div id="example-element">I shrink</div>
      <div id="example-element">Item Two</div>
      <div id="example-element">Item Three</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<p>Added more examples after the first comment. Feel free to resize the screen to see the behaviour</p>
<p>All elements same size, container with flex: 1 1 0;<br>
  <small>Added <b>justify-content: space-evenly;</b> which helps to distribute the extra free space </small>
</p>

<div>
  <section>
    <div class="example-container second-solution">
      <div>Item one</div>
      <div>Item Two</div>
      <div>Item Three</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<p>Suggestion: using flex-wrap: wrap; on the container so the items will always fit the container</p>
<div>
  <section>
    <div class="example-container third-solution">
      <div>Item one</div>
      <div>Item Two</div>
      <div>Item Three</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this could be helpful. In your example, only the "I shrink" element is the right size. Any idea how I could do this with all three elements?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code snippet from my answer, have a look on it.

If you set them so that their `flex-basis` is 0  all elements will have the same starting point and the ability to grow.

`container{
    flex: 1 1 0;
}
`

Answer (score -1):

Can you paste your code here so we can see more info about your problem. Also did you try with flex-grow property?

Comment: Do not post a comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's the HTML code:

`<nav id="categories">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">`

And that's the CSS:

`#categories ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    padding: 7px 0 0 0;
}

#categories li {
    padding: 0 0 7px 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
}`

I don't understand how the flex-grow property could fix this.The only thing I want is for the list elements to take up the space they need and not more than that.